# How to add null fields to preceding sibling elements where the subsequent elements do have a value? See example

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

**I have the following XML:**

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <LaborTaskInterface>
          <LaborTask thing1="a" thing2="c" thing3="d" thing4="e" thing5="f" 
          thing6="g" thing7="h" thing8="i" thing9="j">
                <ltOverride unit_id="1" value="1" thing2="k" thing3="c" thing4="d" thing10="o"/>
                <ltOverride unit_id="2" value="1" thing2="l" thing3="c" thing4="d" thing11="p"/>
                <ltOverride unit_id="3" value="1" thing2="m" thing3="c" thing4="d" thing12="q"/>
                <ltOverride unit_id="4" value="1" thing2="n" thing3="c" thing4="d" thing13="r"/>
         </LaborTask>
         <LaborTask thing1="aa" thing2="bb" thing3="dd" thing4="ee" thing5="ff" 
          thing6="gg" thing7="hh" thing8="ii" thing9="jj">
                <ltOverride unit_id="11" value="11" thing2="kk" thing3="cc" thing4="dd" thing10="oo"/>
                <ltOverride unit_id="22" value="12" thing2="ll" thing3="cc" thing4="dd" thing11="pp"/>
                <ltOverride unit_id="33" value="13" thing2="mm" thing3="cc" thing4="dd" thing12="qq"/>
                <ltOverride unit_id="44" value="14" thing2="nn" thing3="cc" thing4="dd" thing13="rr"/>
          </LaborTask>
    </LaborTaskInterface>
```

**I have currently been able to transform and import this into Microsoft Access using the following XSLT-1.0:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:key name="group" match="ltOverride/*" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', name())"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="LaborTask">
    <xsl:variable name="temp-data">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ltOverride" mode="attributes-to-elements"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($temp-data)/ltOverride">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', concat(generate-id(..), '|', name()))[1])]">
          <xsl:for-each select="key('group', concat(generate-id(..), '|', name()))">
            <xsl:variable name="index">
              <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('.', position())"/>
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:element name="{name()}{$index}">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>        
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="ltOverride" mode="attributes-to-elements">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../@* | @*" mode="attributes-to-elements"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="@*" mode="attributes-to-elements">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**This provides the following output:**

```html
<LaborTaskInterface>
    <ltOverride>
      <thing1>a</thing1>
      <thing2>c</thing2>
      <thing2.2>k</thing2.2>
      <thing3>d</thing3>
      <thing3.2>c</thing3.2>
      <thing4>e</thing4>
      <thing4.2>d</thing4.2>
      <thing5>f</thing5>
      <thing6>g</thing6>
      <thing7>h</thing7>
      <thing8>i</thing8>
      <thing9>j</thing9>
      <unit_id>1</unit_id>
      <value>1</value>
      <thing10>o</thing10>
   </ltOverride>
   <ltOverride>
      <thing1>a</thing1>
      <thing2>c</thing2>
      <thing2.2>l</thing2.2>
      <thing3>d</thing3>
      <thing3.2>c</thing3.2>
      <thing4>e</thing4>
      <thing4.2>d</thing4.2>
      <thing5>f</thing5>
      <thing6>g</thing6>
      <thing7>h</thing7>
      <thing8>i</thing8>
      <thing9>j</thing9>
      <unit_id>2</unit_id>
      <value>1</value>
      <thing11>p</thing11>
   </ltOverride>
   <ltOverride>
      <thing1>a</thing1>
      <thing2>c</thing2>
      <thing2.2>m</thing2.2>
      <thing3>d</thing3>
      <thing3.2>c</thing3.2>
      <thing4>e</thing4>
      <thing4.2>d</thing4.2>
      <thing5>f</thing5>
      <thing6>g</thing6>
      <thing7>h</thing7>
      <thing8>i</thing8>
      <thing9>j</thing9>
      <unit_id>3</unit_id>
      <value>1</value>
      <thing12>q</thing12>
   </ltOverride>
   <ltOverride>
      <thing1>a</thing1>
      <thing2>c</thing2>
      <thing2.2>n</thing2.2>
      <thing3>d</thing3>
      <thing3.2>c</thing3.2>
      <thing4>e</thing4>
      <thing4.2>d</thing4.2>
      <thing5>f</thing5>
      <thing6>g</thing6>
      <thing7>h</thing7>
      <thing8>i</thing8>
      <thing9>j</thing9>
      <unit_id>4</unit_id>
      <value>1</value>
      <thing13>r</thing13>
   </ltOverride>
   <ltOverride>
      <thing1>aa</thing1>
      <thing2>bb</thing2>
      <thing2.2>kk</thing2.2>
      <thing3>dd</thing3>
      <thing3.2>cc</thing3.2>
      <thing4>ee</thing4>
      <thing4.2>dd</thing4.2>
      <thing5>ff</thing5>
      <thing6>gg</thing6>
      <thing7>hh</thing7>
      <thing8>ii</thing8>
      <thing9>jj</thing9>
      <unit_id>11</unit_id>
      <value>11</value>
      <thing10>oo</thing10>
   </ltOverride>
   <ltOverride>
      <thing1>aa</thing1>
      <thing2>bb</thing2>
      <thing2.2>ll</thing2.2>
      <thing3>dd</thing3>
      <thing3.2>cc</thing3.2>
      <thing4>ee</thing4>
      <thing4.2>dd</thing4.2>
      <thing5>ff</thing5>
      <thing6>gg</thing6>
      <thing7>hh</thing7>
      <thing8>ii</thing8>
      <thing9>jj</thing9>
      <unit_id>22</unit_id>
      <value>12</value>
      <thing11>pp</thing11>
   </ltOverride>
   <ltOverride>
      <thing1>aa</thing1>
      <thing2>bb</thing2>
      <thing2.2>mm</thing2.2>
      <thing3>dd</thing3>
      <thing3.2>cc</thing3.2>
      <thing4>ee</thing4>
      <thing4.2>dd</thing4.2>
      <thing5>ff</thing5>
      <thing6>gg</thing6>
      <thing7>hh</thing7>
      <thing8>ii</thing8>
      <thing9>jj</thing9>
      <unit_id>33</unit_id>
      <value>13</value>
      <thing12>qq</thing12>
   </ltOverride>
   <ltOverride>
      <thing1>aa</thing1>
      <thing2>bb</thing2>
      <thing2.2>nn</thing2.2>
      <thing3>dd</thing3>
      <thing3.2>cc</thing3.2>
      <thing4>ee</thing4>
      <thing4.2>dd</thing4.2>
      <thing5>ff</thing5>
      <thing6>gg</thing6>
      <thing7>hh</thing7>
      <thing8>ii</thing8>
      <thing9>jj</thing9>
      <unit_id>44</unit_id>
      <value>14</value>
      <thing13>rr</thing13>
   </ltOverride>
</LaborTaskInterface>
```

**I would like the following output (note how thing10 - thing13 exist for all instances of ItOverride, each instance has the value filled for the respective "thingXX" but null for the non-existent values. Also, for the sake of simplicity, aa and bb . . . xx represent completely new values, not 2xa etc):**

```html
<LaborTaskInterface>
          <ltOverride>
          <thing1>a</thing1>
          <thing2>c</thing2>
          <thing2.2>k</thing2.2>
          <thing3>d</thing3>
          <thing3.2>c</thing3.2>
          <thing4>e</thing4>
          <thing4.2>d</thing4.2>
          <thing5>f</thing5>
          <thing6>g</thing6>
          <thing7>h</thing7>
          <thing8>i</thing8>
          <thing9>j</thing9>
          <unit_id>1</unit_id>
          <value>1</value>
          <thing10>o</thing10>
          <thing11></thing11>
          <thing12></thing12>
          <thing13></thing13>
       </ltOverride>
       <ltOverride>
          <thing1>a</thing1>
          <thing2>c</thing2>
          <thing2.2>l</thing2.2>
          <thing3>d</thing3>
          <thing3.2>c</thing3.2>
          <thing4>e</thing4>
          <thing4.2>d</thing4.2>
          <thing5>f</thing5>
          <thing6>g</thing6>
          <thing7>h</thing7>
          <thing8>i</thing8>
          <thing9>j</thing9>
          <unit_id>2</unit_id>
          <value>1</value>
          <thing10></thing10>
          <thing11>p</thing11>
          <thing12></thing12>
          <thing13></thing13>
       </ltOverride>
       <ltOverride>
          <thing1>a</thing1>
          <thing2>c</thing2>
          <thing2.2>m</thing2.2>
          <thing3>d</thing3>
          <thing3.2>c</thing3.2>
          <thing4>e</thing4>
          <thing4.2>d</thing4.2>
          <thing5>f</thing5>
          <thing6>g</thing6>
          <thing7>h</thing7>
          <thing8>i</thing8>
          <thing9>j</thing9>
          <unit_id>3</unit_id>
          <value>1</value>
          <thing10></thing10>
          <thing11></thing11>
          <thing12>q</thing12>
          <thing13></thing13>
       </ltOverride>
       <ltOverride>
          <thing1>a</thing1>
          <thing2>c</thing2>
          <thing2.2>n</thing2.2>
          <thing3>d</thing3>
          <thing3.2>c</thing3.2>
          <thing4>e</thing4>
          <thing4.2>d</thing4.2>
          <thing5>f</thing5>
          <thing6>g</thing6>
          <thing7>h</thing7>
          <thing8>i</thing8>
          <thing9>j</thing9>
          <unit_id>4</unit_id>
          <value>1</value>
          <thing10></thing10>
          <thing11></thing11>
          <thing12></thing12>
          <thing13>r</thing13>
       </ltOverride>
       <ltOverride>
          <thing1>aa</thing1>
          <thing2>bb</thing2>
          <thing2.2>kk</thing2.2>
          <thing3>dd</thing3>
          <thing3.2>cc</thing3.2>
          <thing4>ee</thing4>
          <thing4.2>dd</thing4.2>
          <thing5>ff</thing5>
          <thing6>gg</thing6>
          <thing7>hh</thing7>
          <thing8>ii</thing8>
          <thing9>jj</thing9>
          <unit_id>11</unit_id>
          <value>11</value>
          <thing10>oo</thing10>
          <thing11></thing11>
          <thing12></thing12>
          <thing13></thing13>
       </ltOverride>
       <ltOverride>
          <thing1>aa</thing1>
          <thing2>bb</thing2>
          <thing2.2>ll</thing2.2>
          <thing3>dd</thing3>
          <thing3.2>cc</thing3.2>
          <thing4>ee</thing4>
          <thing4.2>dd</thing4.2>
          <thing5>ff</thing5>
          <thing6>gg</thing6>
          <thing7>hh</thing7>
          <thing8>ii</thing8>
          <thing9>jj</thing9>
          <unit_id>22</unit_id>
          <value>12</value>
          <thing10></thing10>
          <thing11>pp</thing11>
          <thing12></thing12>
          <thing13></thing13>
       </ltOverride>
       <ltOverride>
          <thing1>aa</thing1>
          <thing2>bb</thing2>
          <thing2.2>mm</thing2.2>
          <thing3>dd</thing3>
          <thing3.2>cc</thing3.2>
          <thing4>ee</thing4>
          <thing4.2>dd</thing4.2>
          <thing5>ff</thing5>
          <thing6>gg</thing6>
          <thing7>hh</thing7>
          <thing8>ii</thing8>
          <thing9>jj</thing9>
          <unit_id>33</unit_id>
          <value>13</value>
          <thing10></thing10>
          <thing11></thing11>
          <thing12>qq</thing12>
          <thing13></thing13>
       </ltOverride>
       <ltOverride>
          <thing1>aa</thing1>
          <thing2>bb</thing2>
          <thing2.2>nn</thing2.2>
          <thing3>dd</thing3>
          <thing3.2>cc</thing3.2>
          <thing4>ee</thing4>
          <thing4.2>dd</thing4.2>
          <thing5>ff</thing5>
          <thing6>gg</thing6>
          <thing7>hh</thing7>
          <thing8>ii</thing8>
          <thing9>jj</thing9>
          <unit_id>44</unit_id>
          <value>14</value>
          <thing10></thing10>
          <thing11></thing11>
          <thing12></thing12>
          <thing13>rr</thing13>
       </ltOverride>
    </LaborTaskInterface>
```

Is the above output possible to achieve?

**I am thinking that it will involve an edit in the following portion of the XSLT:**

```html
  <xsl:template match="LaborTask">
    <xsl:variable name="temp-data">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ltOverride" mode="attributes-to-elements"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($temp-data)/ltOverride">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', concat(generate-id(..), '|',      name()))[1])]">
          <xsl:for-each select="key('group', concat(generate-id(..), '|', name()))">
            <xsl:variable name="index">
              <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('.', position())"/>
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:element name="{name()}{$index}">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>        
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

Aside from feasbility, is there a method to add/change a prior point within an XML when the transform is beyond said point?

**As a side note, I have achieved the import to Access using the following link's guidance:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/import-attribute-centric-xml

**After running the suggested xslt-1.0 below against the updated xml above:**

```html
<LaborTaskInterface>
  <ltOverride>
    <thing1>a</thing1>
    <thing2>c</thing2>
    <thing3>d</thing3>
    <thing4>e</thing4>
    <thing5>f</thing5>
    <thing6>g</thing6>
    <thing7>h</thing7>
    <thing8>i</thing8>
    <thing9>j</thing9>
    <thing1>aa</thing1>
    <thing2>bb</thing2>
    <thing3>dd</thing3>
    <thing4>ee</thing4>
    <thing5>ff</thing5>
    <thing6>gg</thing6>
    <thing7>hh</thing7>
    <thing8>ii</thing8>
    <thing9>jj</thing9>
    <unit_id>1</unit_id>
    <value>1</value>
    <thing2.2>k</thing2.2>
    <thing3.2>c</thing3.2>
    <thing4.2>d</thing4.2>
    <thing10>o</thing10>
    <thing11></thing11>
    <thing12></thing12>
    <thing13></thing13>
  </ltOverride>
  <ltOverride>
    <thing1>a</thing1>
    <thing2>c</thing2>
    <thing3>d</thing3>
    <thing4>e</thing4>
    <thing5>f</thing5>
    <thing6>g</thing6>
    <thing7>h</thing7>
    <thing8>i</thing8>
    <thing9>j</thing9>
    <thing1>aa</thing1>
    <thing2>bb</thing2>
    <thing3>dd</thing3>
    <thing4>ee</thing4>
    <thing5>ff</thing5>
    <thing6>gg</thing6>
    <thing7>hh</thing7>
    <thing8>ii</thing8>
    <thing9>jj</thing9>
    <unit_id>2</unit_id>
    <value>1</value>
    <thing2.2>l</thing2.2>
    <thing3.2>c</thing3.2>
    <thing4.2>d</thing4.2>
    <thing10></thing10>
    <thing11>p</thing11>
    <thing12></thing12>
    <thing13></thing13>
  </ltOverride>
  <ltOverride>
    <thing1>a</thing1>
    <thing2>c</thing2>
    <thing3>d</thing3>
    <thing4>e</thing4>
    <thing5>f</thing5>
    <thing6>g</thing6>
    <thing7>h</thing7>
    <thing8>i</thing8>
    <thing9>j</thing9>
    <thing1>aa</thing1>
    <thing2>bb</thing2>
    <thing3>dd</thing3>
    <thing4>ee</thing4>
    <thing5>ff</thing5>
    <thing6>gg</thing6>
    <thing7>hh</thing7>
    <thing8>ii</thing8>
    <thing9>jj</thing9>
    <unit_id>3</unit_id>
    <value>1</value>
    <thing2.2>m</thing2.2>
    <thing3.2>c</thing3.2>
    <thing4.2>d</thing4.2>
    <thing10></thing10>
    <thing11></thing11>
    <thing12>q</thing12>
    <thing13></thing13>
  </ltOverride>
  <ltOverride>
    <thing1>a</thing1>
    <thing2>c</thing2>
    <thing3>d</thing3>
    <thing4>e</thing4>
    <thing5>f</thing5>
    <thing6>g</thing6>
    <thing7>h</thing7>
    <thing8>i</thing8>
    <thing9>j</thing9>
    <thing1>aa</thing1>
    <thing2>bb</thing2>
    <thing3>dd</thing3>
    <thing4>ee</thing4>
    <thing5>ff</thing5>
    <thing6>gg</thing6>
    <thing7>hh</thing7>
    <thing8>ii</thing8>
    <thing9>jj</thing9>
    <unit_id>4</unit_id>
    <value>1</value>
    <thing2.2>n</thing2.2>
    <thing3.2>c</thing3.2>
    <thing4.2>d</thing4.2>
    <thing10></thing10>
    <thing11></thing11>
    <thing12></thing12>
    <thing13>r</thing13>
  </ltOverride>
  <ltOverride>
    <thing1>a</thing1>
    <thing2>c</thing2>
    <thing3>d</thing3>
    <thing4>e</thing4>
    <thing5>f</thing5>
    <thing6>g</thing6>
    <thing7>h</thing7>
    <thing8>i</thing8>
    <thing9>j</thing9>
    <thing1>aa</thing1>
    <thing2>bb</thing2>
    <thing3>dd</thing3>
    <thing4>ee</thing4>
    <thing5>ff</thing5>
    <thing6>gg</thing6>
    <thing7>hh</thing7>
    <thing8>ii</thing8>
    <thing9>jj</thing9>
    <unit_id>11</unit_id>
    <value>11</value>
    <thing2.2>kk</thing2.2>
    <thing3.2>cc</thing3.2>
    <thing4.2>dd</thing4.2>
    <thing10>oo</thing10>
    <thing11></thing11>
    <thing12></thing12>
    <thing13></thing13>
  </ltOverride>
  <ltOverride>
    <thing1>a</thing1>
    <thing2>c</thing2>
    <thing3>d</thing3>
    <thing4>e</thing4>
    <thing5>f</thing5>
    <thing6>g</thing6>
    <thing7>h</thing7>
    <thing8>i</thing8>
    <thing9>j</thing9>
    <thing1>aa</thing1>
    <thing2>bb</thing2>
    <thing3>dd</thing3>
    <thing4>ee</thing4>
    <thing5>ff</thing5>
    <thing6>gg</thing6>
    <thing7>hh</thing7>
    <thing8>ii</thing8>
    <thing9>jj</thing9>
    <unit_id>22</unit_id>
    <value>12</value>
    <thing2.2>ll</thing2.2>
    <thing3.2>cc</thing3.2>
    <thing4.2>dd</thing4.2>
    <thing10></thing10>
    <thing11>pp</thing11>
    <thing12></thing12>
    <thing13></thing13>
  </ltOverride>
  <ltOverride>
    <thing1>a</thing1>
    <thing2>c</thing2>
    <thing3>d</thing3>
    <thing4>e</thing4>
    <thing5>f</thing5>
    <thing6>g</thing6>
    <thing7>h</thing7>
    <thing8>i</thing8>
    <thing9>j</thing9>
    <thing1>aa</thing1>
    <thing2>bb</thing2>
    <thing3>dd</thing3>
    <thing4>ee</thing4>
    <thing5>ff</thing5>
    <thing6>gg</thing6>
    <thing7>hh</thing7>
    <thing8>ii</thing8>
    <thing9>jj</thing9>
    <unit_id>33</unit_id>
    <value>13</value>
    <thing2.2>mm</thing2.2>
    <thing3.2>cc</thing3.2>
    <thing4.2>dd</thing4.2>
    <thing10></thing10>
    <thing11></thing11>
    <thing12>qq</thing12>
    <thing13></thing13>
  </ltOverride>
  <ltOverride>
    <thing1>a</thing1>
    <thing2>c</thing2>
    <thing3>d</thing3>
    <thing4>e</thing4>
    <thing5>f</thing5>
    <thing6>g</thing6>
    <thing7>h</thing7>
    <thing8>i</thing8>
    <thing9>j</thing9>
    <thing1>aa</thing1>
    <thing2>bb</thing2>
    <thing3>dd</thing3>
    <thing4>ee</thing4>
    <thing5>ff</thing5>
    <thing6>gg</thing6>
    <thing7>hh</thing7>
    <thing8>ii</thing8>
    <thing9>jj</thing9>
    <unit_id>44</unit_id>
    <value>14</value>
    <thing2.2>nn</thing2.2>
    <thing3.2>cc</thing3.2>
    <thing4.2>dd</thing4.2>
    <thing10></thing10>
    <thing11></thing11>
    <thing12></thing12>
    <thing13>rr</thing13>
  </ltOverride>
</LaborTaskInterface>
```

Comment: Any chance you could simplify the example? Trying to spot the difference between your actual output and your desired output is like one of those puzzles in a children's comic - you're not making things easy for us. I'm sure the problem could be illustrated with much simpler data.

Comment: @MichaelKay I have expanded my explanation in the intro to the desired output. I am not sure what the scientific explanation/description of my dilemma would be other than persisting that of all sibling instances (null for the non-existent)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will have to make a radical change to your approach. Maybe something like this:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
extension-element-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="attr-by-name" match="ltOverride/@*" use="name()"/>
<xsl:key name="value" match="ltOverride/@*" use="concat(name(), generate-id(..))"/>

<xsl:template match="/LaborTaskInterface">
    <xsl:variable name="xml" select="/" />
    <!-- base -->
    <xsl:variable name="base-attr" select="LaborTask/@*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="base-elems">
        <xsl:for-each select="$base-attr">
            <xsl:element name="{name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- override -->
    <xsl:variable name="override-columns">
        <xsl:for-each select="LaborTask/ltOverride/@*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('attr-by-name', name())[1])]">
            <col name="{name()}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>      
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="LaborTask/ltOverride">
                <xsl:variable name="id" select="generate-id()" />
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$base-elems"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($override-columns)/col">
                        <xsl:variable name="name" select="@name" />
                        <xsl:variable name="dup">
                            <xsl:if test="$base-attr[name() = $name]">.2</xsl:if>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <xsl:element name="{@name}{$dup}">
                            <!-- switch context back to input document in order to use key -->
                            <xsl:for-each select="$xml">
                                <xsl:value-of select="key('value', concat($name, $id))" />
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

AFAICT the result is identical to the expected output, except for the order of elements representing the columns.

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiorv1Z

Comment: This achieves the addition of the fields, but when ran against the above (I edited for the sake of demonstrating the short comings) this is the output (posted above as an update.

Comment: @JustinW Your practice of constantly changing and expanding your requirements after getting an answer is not helpful to your cause (to put it mildly). Luckily for you, the required change is rather trivial: simply create the `$base-elems` variable separately for each `LaborTask`.

Comment: When you say separately for each task, is there a way to easily repeat this when there are 408 separate LaborTask? Depending on the simulation ran, this value is quite variable.

Comment: That's what `xsl:for-each` is for.

Comment: Would the for each in this case replace the copy of or supplement it? Additionally, the $base-elems is called in both the base and the output. I see that xsl:for-each has been used within the $base-attr as well within the base section. Would I need it there and in the ouput?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to answer your question. As I said, the adjustment is rather trivial. However, this is not a simple task overall, and the stylesheet is rather complex. You need to be at least at intermediate level to understand it sufficiently to make changes. I cannot bring you to the required level by jotting a few words in a comment.

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of the "base", "override" and "output" sections in the above solution? Just from examining the code I understand the that the $base-attr is in reference to the attributes of each ItOverride node, I am assuming that $base-elem would be in reference to that of the LaborTask element. As you've already explained, for-each serves as a loop function, I'm also aware from W3C that copy-of legitimately copies that of the LaborTask element and the reason that it repeats the first LaborTask for my actual XML is due to copy-of. But the solution will include both the copy & each

Comment: The *base* section converts the attributes of `LaborTask` to elements. The *override* section creates the additional columns (names only)  that will appear in each `ltOverride` of the output. Both of these are preliminary steps that result in variables. The *output* section creates the actual output. Part of the output is created by copying the contents of the `$base-elems` variable The other part is created by finding the value for each `col` in the `override-columns` variable and creating an element by combining the name and the value.