# How to copy each parent into child elements?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

**I have the following XML:**

```html
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <LaborTaskInterface>
          <LaborTask thing100="a" thing2="c" thing3="d" thing4="e" thing500="f" 
          thing6="g" thing7="h" thing8="i" thing9="j">
                <ltOverride unit_id="1" value="1" thing2="k" thing3="c" thing4="d" thing10="o" thing500="z"/>
                <ltOverride unit_id="2" value="1" thing2="l" thing3="c" thing4="d" thing11="p" thing500="z"/>
                <ltOverride unit_id="3" value="1" thing2="m" thing3="c" thing4="d" thing12="q" thing500="z"/>
                <ltOverride unit_id="4" value="1" thing2="n" thing3="c" thing4="d" thing13="r" thing500="z"/>
         </LaborTask>
         <LaborTask thing1="aa" thing2="bb" thing3="dd" thing4="ee" thing5="ff" 
          thing6="gg" thing7="hh" thing8="ii" thing9="jj" thing14="xx">
                <ltOverride unit_id="11" value="11" thing2="kk" thing3="cc" thing4="dd" thing10="oo" thing14="yy"/>
                <ltOverride unit_id="22" value="12" thing2="ll" thing3="cc" thing4="dd" thing11="pp" thing14="yy"/>
                <ltOverride unit_id="33" value="13" thing2="mm" thing3="cc" thing4="dd" thing12="qq" thing14="yy"/>
                <ltOverride unit_id="44" value="14" thing2="nn" thing3="cc" thing4="dd" thing13="rr" thing14="yy"/>
          </LaborTask>
    </LaborTaskInterface>
```

I am attempting to persist/copy each instance of LaborTask into each of the subsequent ItOverride and eliminate the LaborTask node so as to only have one table (ItOverride).

**I am using the following XSLT-1.0 (as XSLT-1.0 is a requirement due to Microsoft Access):**

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
extension-element-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="attr-by-name" match="ltOverride/@*" use="name()"/>
<xsl:key name="value" match="ltOverride/@*" use="concat(name(), generate-id(..))"/>

<xsl:template match="/LaborTaskInterface">
    <xsl:variable name="xml" select="/" />
    <!-- base -->
    <xsl:variable name="base-attr" select="LaborTask/@*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="base-elems">
        <xsl:for-each select="$base-attr">
            <xsl:element name="{name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- override -->
    <xsl:variable name="override-columns">
        <xsl:for-each select="LaborTask/ltOverride/@*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('attr-by-name', name())[1])]">
            <col name="{name()}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>      
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="LaborTask/ltOverride">
                <xsl:variable name="id" select="generate-id()" />
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$base-elems"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$base-elems"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($override-columns)/col">
                        <xsl:variable name="name" select="@name" />
                        <xsl:variable name="dup">
                            <xsl:if test="$base-attr[name() = $name]">.2</xsl:if>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <xsl:element name="{@name}{$dup}">
                            <!-- switch context back to input document in order to use key -->
                            <xsl:for-each select="$xml">
                                <xsl:value-of select="key('value', concat($name, $id))" />
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**This is the output I am getting which is not desired (I have attempted to loop the $base-elem):**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<LaborTaskInterface>
  <ltOverride>
    <thing1>a</thing1>
    <thing2>c</thing2>
    <thing3>d</thing3>
    <thing4>e</thing4>
    <thing5>f</thing5>
    <thing6>g</thing6>
    <thing7>h</thing7>
    <thing8>i</thing8>
    <thing9>j</thing9>
    <thing1>aa</thing1>
    <thing2>bb</thing2>
    <thing3>dd</thing3>
    <thing4>ee</thing4>
    <thing5>ff</thing5>
    <thing6>gg</thing6>
    <thing7>hh</thing7>
    <thing8>ii</thing8>
    <thing9>jj</thing9>
    <unit_id>1</unit_id>
    <value>1</value>
    <thing2.2>k</thing2.2>
    <thing3.2>c</thing3.2>
    <thing4.2>d</thing4.2>
    <thing10>o</thing10>
    <thing11></thing11>
    <thing12></thing12>
    <thing13></thing13>
  </ltOverride>
  <ltOverride>
    <thing1>a</thing1>
    <thing2>c</thing2>
    <thing3>d</thing3>
    <thing4>e</thing4>
    <thing5>f</thing5>
    <thing6>g</thing6>
    <thing7>h</thing7>
    <thing8>i</thing8>
    <thing9>j</thing9>
    <thing1>aa</thing1>
    <thing2>bb</thing2>
    <thing3>dd</thing3>
    <thing4>ee</thing4>
    <thing5>ff</thing5>
    <thing6>gg</thing6>
    <thing7>hh</thing7>
    <thing8>ii</thing8>
    <thing9>jj</thing9>
    <unit_id>2</unit_id>
    <value>1</value>
    <thing2.2>l</thing2.2>
    <thing3.2>c</thing3.2>
    <thing4.2>d</thing4.2>
    <thing10></thing10>
    <thing11>p</thing11>
    <thing12></thing12>
    <thing13></thing13>
  </ltOverride>
  <ltOverride>
    <thing1>a</thing1>
    <thing2>c</thing2>
    <thing3>d</thing3>
    <thing4>e</thing4>
    <thing5>f</thing5>
    <thing6>g</thing6>
    <thing7>h</thing7>
    <thing8>i</thing8>
    <thing9>j</thing9>
    <thing1>aa</thing1>
    <thing2>bb</thing2>
    <thing3>dd</thing3>
    <thing4>ee</thing4>
    <thing5>ff</thing5>
    <thing6>gg</thing6>
    <thing7>hh</thing7>
    <thing8>ii</thing8>
    <thing9>jj</thing9>
    <unit_id>3</unit_id>
    <value>1</value>
    <thing2.2>m</thing2.2>
    <thing3.2>c</thing3.2>
    <thing4.2>d</thing4.2>
    <thing10></thing10>
    <thing11></thing11>
    <thing12>q</thing12>
    <thing13></thing13>
  </ltOverride>
  <ltOverride>
    <thing1>a</thing1>
    <thing2>c</thing2>
    <thing3>d</thing3>
    <thing4>e</thing4>
    <thing5>f</thing5>
    <thing6>g</thing6>
    <thing7>h</thing7>
    <thing8>i</thing8>
    <thing9>j</thing9>
    <thing1>aa</thing1>
    <thing2>bb</thing2>
    <thing3>dd</thing3>
    <thing4>ee</thing4>
    <thing5>ff</thing5>
    <thing6>gg</thing6>
    <thing7>hh</thing7>
    <thing8>ii</thing8>
    <thing9>jj</thing9>
    <unit_id>4</unit_id>
    <value>1</value>
    <thing2.2>n</thing2.2>
    <thing3.2>c</thing3.2>
    <thing4.2>d</thing4.2>
    <thing10></thing10>
    <thing11></thing11>
    <thing12></thing12>
    <thing13>r</thing13>
  </ltOverride>
  <ltOverride>
    <thing1>a</thing1>
    <thing2>c</thing2>
    <thing3>d</thing3>
    <thing4>e</thing4>
    <thing5>f</thing5>
    <thing6>g</thing6>
    <thing7>h</thing7>
    <thing8>i</thing8>
    <thing9>j</thing9>
    <thing1>aa</thing1>
    <thing2>bb</thing2>
    <thing3>dd</thing3>
    <thing4>ee</thing4>
    <thing5>ff</thing5>
    <thing6>gg</thing6>
    <thing7>hh</thing7>
    <thing8>ii</thing8>
    <thing9>jj</thing9>
    <unit_id>11</unit_id>
    <value>11</value>
    <thing2.2>kk</thing2.2>
    <thing3.2>cc</thing3.2>
    <thing4.2>dd</thing4.2>
    <thing10>oo</thing10>
    <thing11></thing11>
    <thing12></thing12>
    <thing13></thing13>
  </ltOverride>
  <ltOverride>
    <thing1>a</thing1>
    <thing2>c</thing2>
    <thing3>d</thing3>
    <thing4>e</thing4>
    <thing5>f</thing5>
    <thing6>g</thing6>
    <thing7>h</thing7>
    <thing8>i</thing8>
    <thing9>j</thing9>
    <thing1>aa</thing1>
    <thing2>bb</thing2>
    <thing3>dd</thing3>
    <thing4>ee</thing4>
    <thing5>ff</thing5>
    <thing6>gg</thing6>
    <thing7>hh</thing7>
    <thing8>ii</thing8>
    <thing9>jj</thing9>
    <unit_id>22</unit_id>
    <value>12</value>
    <thing2.2>ll</thing2.2>
    <thing3.2>cc</thing3.2>
    <thing4.2>dd</thing4.2>
    <thing10></thing10>
    <thing11>pp</thing11>
    <thing12></thing12>
    <thing13></thing13>
  </ltOverride>
  <ltOverride>
    <thing1>a</thing1>
    <thing2>c</thing2>
    <thing3>d</thing3>
    <thing4>e</thing4>
    <thing5>f</thing5>
    <thing6>g</thing6>
    <thing7>h</thing7>
    <thing8>i</thing8>
    <thing9>j</thing9>
    <thing1>aa</thing1>
    <thing2>bb</thing2>
    <thing3>dd</thing3>
    <thing4>ee</thing4>
    <thing5>ff</thing5>
    <thing6>gg</thing6>
    <thing7>hh</thing7>
    <thing8>ii</thing8>
    <thing9>jj</thing9>
    <unit_id>33</unit_id>
    <value>13</value>
    <thing2.2>mm</thing2.2>
    <thing3.2>cc</thing3.2>
    <thing4.2>dd</thing4.2>
    <thing10></thing10>
    <thing11></thing11>
    <thing12>qq</thing12>
    <thing13></thing13>
  </ltOverride>
  <ltOverride>
    <thing1>a</thing1>
    <thing2>c</thing2>
    <thing3>d</thing3>
    <thing4>e</thing4>
    <thing5>f</thing5>
    <thing6>g</thing6>
    <thing7>h</thing7>
    <thing8>i</thing8>
    <thing9>j</thing9>
    <thing1>aa</thing1>
    <thing2>bb</thing2>
    <thing3>dd</thing3>
    <thing4>ee</thing4>
    <thing5>ff</thing5>
    <thing6>gg</thing6>
    <thing7>hh</thing7>
    <thing8>ii</thing8>
    <thing9>jj</thing9>
    <unit_id>44</unit_id>
    <value>14</value>
    <thing2.2>nn</thing2.2>
    <thing3.2>cc</thing3.2>
    <thing4.2>dd</thing4.2>
    <thing10></thing10>
    <thing11></thing11>
    <thing12></thing12>
    <thing13>rr</thing13>
  </ltOverride>
</LaborTaskInterface>
```

You can see in the above output that the first instance of LaborTask (where thing1="a") is being brought into each of the 8 ItOverride.

**This is the desired output (note how the first instance of LaborTask is carried into the first 4 ItOverride and the second instance of LaborTask is carried into the next 4 instances of ItOverride):**

```html
<LaborTaskInterface>
       <ltOverride>
          <thing1></thing1>
          <thing100>a</thing100>
          <thing2>c</thing2>
          <thing2.2>k</thing2.2>
          <thing3>d</thing3>
          <thing3.2>c</thing3.2>
          <thing4>e</thing4>
          <thing4.2>d</thing4.2>
          <thing5>f</thing5>
          <thing6>g</thing6>
          <thing7>h</thing7>
          <thing8>i</thing8>
          <thing9>j</thing9>
          <unit_id>1</unit_id>
          <value>1</value>
          <thing10>o</thing10>
          <thing11></thing11>
          <thing12></thing12>
          <thing13></thing13>
          <thing14></thing14>
          <thing14.2></thing14.2>
          <thing500>f</thing500>
       </ltOverride>
       <ltOverride>
          <thing1></thing1>
          <thing100>a</thing100>
          <thing2>c</thing2>
          <thing2.2>l</thing2.2>
          <thing3>d</thing3>
          <thing3.2>c</thing3.2>
          <thing4>e</thing4>
          <thing4.2>d</thing4.2>
          <thing5>f</thing5>
          <thing6>g</thing6>
          <thing7>h</thing7>
          <thing8>i</thing8>
          <thing9>j</thing9>
          <unit_id>2</unit_id>
          <value>1</value>
          <thing10></thing10>
          <thing11>p</thing11>
          <thing12></thing12>
          <thing13></thing13>
          <thing14></thing14>
          <thing14.2></thing14.2>
          <thing500>f</thing500>
       </ltOverride>
       <ltOverride>
          <thing1></thing1>
          <thing100>a</thing100>
          <thing2>c</thing2>
          <thing2.2>m</thing2.2>
          <thing3>d</thing3>
          <thing3.2>c</thing3.2>
          <thing4>e</thing4>
          <thing4.2>d</thing4.2>
          <thing5>f</thing5>
          <thing6>g</thing6>
          <thing7>h</thing7>
          <thing8>i</thing8>
          <thing9>j</thing9>
          <unit_id>3</unit_id>
          <value>1</value>
          <thing10></thing10>
          <thing11></thing11>
          <thing12>q</thing12>
          <thing13></thing13>
          <thing14></thing14>
          <thing14.2></thing14.2>
          <thing500>f</thing500>
       </ltOverride>
       <ltOverride>
          <thing1></thing1>
          <thing100>a</thing100>
          <thing2>c</thing2>
          <thing2.2>n</thing2.2>
          <thing3>d</thing3>
          <thing3.2>c</thing3.2>
          <thing4>e</thing4>
          <thing4.2>d</thing4.2>
          <thing5>f</thing5>
          <thing6>g</thing6>
          <thing7>h</thing7>
          <thing8>i</thing8>
          <thing9>j</thing9>
          <unit_id>4</unit_id>
          <value>1</value>
          <thing10></thing10>
          <thing11></thing11>
          <thing12></thing12>
          <thing13>r</thing13>
          <thing14></thing14>
          <thing14.2></thing14.2>
          <thing500>f</thing500>
       </ltOverride>
       <ltOverride>
          <thing1>aa</thing1>
          <thing100></thing100>
          <thing2>bb</thing2>
          <thing2.2>kk</thing2.2>
          <thing3>dd</thing3>
          <thing3.2>cc</thing3.2>
          <thing4>ee</thing4>
          <thing4.2>dd</thing4.2>
          <thing5>ff</thing5>
          <thing6>gg</thing6>
          <thing7>hh</thing7>
          <thing8>ii</thing8>
          <thing9>jj</thing9>
          <unit_id>11</unit_id>
          <value>11</value>
          <thing10>oo</thing10>
          <thing11></thing11>
          <thing12></thing12>
          <thing13></thing13>
          <thing14>xx</thing14>
          <thing14.2>yy</thing14.2>
          <thing500></thing500>
       </ltOverride>
       <ltOverride>
          <thing1>aa</thing1>
          <thing100></thing100>
          <thing2>bb</thing2>
          <thing2.2>ll</thing2.2>
          <thing3>dd</thing3>
          <thing3.2>cc</thing3.2>
          <thing4>ee</thing4>
          <thing4.2>dd</thing4.2>
          <thing5>ff</thing5>
          <thing6>gg</thing6>
          <thing7>hh</thing7>
          <thing8>ii</thing8>
          <thing9>jj</thing9>
          <unit_id>22</unit_id>
          <value>12</value>
          <thing10></thing10>
          <thing11>pp</thing11>
          <thing12></thing12>
          <thing13></thing13>
          <thing14>xx</thing14>
          <thing14.2>yy</thing14.2>
          <thing500></thing500>
       </ltOverride>
       <ltOverride>
          <thing1>aa</thing1>
          <thing100></thing100>
          <thing2>bb</thing2>
          <thing2.2>mm</thing2.2>
          <thing3>dd</thing3>
          <thing3.2>cc</thing3.2>
          <thing4>ee</thing4>
          <thing4.2>dd</thing4.2>
          <thing5>ff</thing5>
          <thing6>gg</thing6>
          <thing7>hh</thing7>
          <thing8>ii</thing8>
          <thing9>jj</thing9>
          <unit_id>33</unit_id>
          <value>13</value>
          <thing10></thing10>
          <thing11></thing11>
          <thing12>qq</thing12>
          <thing13></thing13>
          <thing14>xx</thing14>
          <thing14.2>yy</thing14.2>
          <thing500></thing500>
       </ltOverride>
       <ltOverride>
          <thing1>aa</thing1>
          <thing100></thing100>
          <thing2>bb</thing2>
          <thing2.2>nn</thing2.2>
          <thing3>dd</thing3>
          <thing3.2>cc</thing3.2>
          <thing4>ee</thing4>
          <thing4.2>dd</thing4.2>
          <thing5>ff</thing5>
          <thing6>gg</thing6>
          <thing7>hh</thing7>
          <thing8>ii</thing8>
          <thing9>jj</thing9>
          <unit_id>44</unit_id>
          <value>14</value>
          <thing10></thing10>
          <thing11></thing11>
          <thing12></thing12>
          <thing13>rr</thing13>
          <thing14>xx</thing14>
          <thing14.2>yy</thing14.2>
          <thing500></thing500>
       </ltOverride>
    </LaborTaskInterface>
```

Thank you for all help.

Comment: This is a continuation of https://stackoverflow.com/q/71210086/3016153 - which in itself is a continuation of all of OP's questions so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revised XSLT

```
<xsl:variable name="attributeNames">
  <xsl:for-each select="//LaborTask/@*|//ltOverride/@*">
    <xsl:element name="name">
      <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
    
<!-- Use your own namespace instead of msxml. -->
<xsl:variable name="attributeNameList" select="msxml:node-set($attributeNames)"/>
  
<xsl:variable name="distintAttributeNames">
  <xsl:copy-of select="$attributeNameList/name[not(. = preceding-sibling::name)]"/>
</xsl:variable>

<!-- Use your own namespace instead of msxml. -->
<xsl:variable name="distintChildAttributeNameList" select="msxml:node-set($distintAttributeNames)"/>

<xsl:template match="LaborTaskInterface">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="LaborTask">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
    <xsl:with-param name="LaborTaskAttributes" select="@*"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ltOverride">
  <xsl:param name="LaborTaskAttributes"/>
  
  <xsl:variable name="ltOverride" select="@*"/>
  
  <xsl:variable name="emptyAttributes">
    <xsl:element name="holder">
      <xsl:for-each select="$distintChildAttributeNameList/name">
        <xsl:variable name="name" select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="not($LaborTaskAttributes[name() = $name] or $ltOverride[name() = $name])">
          <xsl:attribute name="{$name}"/>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:variable>

  <!-- Use your own namespace instead of msxml. -->
  <xsl:variable name="emptyAttributesList" select="msxml:node-set($emptyAttributes)"/>
      
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$LaborTaskAttributes|@*|$emptyAttributesList/holder/@*">
      <xsl:sort select="name()" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="LaborTaskAttributes" select="$LaborTaskAttributes"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:param name="LaborTaskAttributes"/>
  
  <xsl:variable name="id" select="generate-id(.)"/>
  
  <xsl:variable name="nm" select="name()"/>

  <xsl:variable name="name">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not($LaborTaskAttributes[name() = $nm])">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$LaborTaskAttributes[generate-id(.) = $id]">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), '.2')"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>
  
  <xsl:element name="{$name}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()">
  <xsl:param name="LaborTaskAttributes"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
    <xsl:with-param name="LaborTaskAttributes" select="$LaborTaskAttributes"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I have gotten this to work, but for some reason, it isn't picking up all attributes that exist further in my actual XML document. Is the stylesheet above built to accommodate more instances of LaborTask than just 2? The order isn't an issue as long as it is consistent throughout the XML.

Comment: I have updated the XML above. This XSLT isn't picking up the items in subsequent LaborTask that don't exist in preceding LaborTask. Would it be possible for you to edit this XSLT to include that? Thank you for all help!

Comment: I revised the code for you.  Let me know how it goes.

Comment: It's nearly perfect. when debugging against our actual XML, I found that ItOverride specific items weren't coming in such as the 14.2 above in the desired (i updated the sample XML to demonstrate). Aside from that, it appears to hit hit all requirements! Is this something you think would be an easy fix? Thank you so much!

Comment: (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiorv1Z/8) note how the ItOverride specific attribute thing14 does not create a 14.2 instance in preceding ItOverride elements. Aside from this, everything looks to be functioning perfectly. Similarly, ItOverride specific thing500 does not show up as thing500.2 in the ItOverride's within the following LaborTask either.

Comment: So when I run the XSLT against the XML that you supplied.  14.2 gets created in the last 4 ltOverride elements.  It's not in the first 4 elements because it's not an attribute in LaborTask.  Are you saying 14.2 needs to be in the first 4 elements also?

Comment: If possible, yes (as a null value), the reason is because Microsoft Access creates the table off of the first Element (not sure why/how Access acts this way).

Comment: I think I met your original requirements and I have shown you a way to do what you want.   There are other ways.  But, there is enough here for you to work with.  Essentially, you can put all of the possible attribute names in the attributeNames variable.  To do this you'll have to analyze the attributes in the LaborTask elements compared to attributes in the ltOverride elements.  That should be fairly easy.   Much simpler than the XSLT code I wrote for you.  Good luck!

Comment: Which attribute names are currently going into the attributeNames variable? I understand what I need in theory, I just have no clue how to actually code in XSLT (the language that is)

Comment: I have met your original spec.  The problem is I'm busy and can't make adjustments for your additional scope.  If you want I can delete my answer and maybe someone will take this up for you.  Let me know.